# How do I tell Git to ignore everything except a subdirectory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore all files in my repository except those that occur in the `bin` subdirectory. I tried adding the following to my `.gitignore`:

```
*
!bin/*
```

This does not have the desired effect, however: I created a new file inside of `bin/`, but doing `git status` still shows `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 340, accepted):

This ignores root files & root directories, then un-ignores the root bin directory:

```
/*
/*/
!/bin/
```

This way you get all of the bin directory, including subdirectories and their files.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work consistently for me. I have the two lines `/stuff/` and `!/stuff/specific/`, but it still ignores /stuff/specific/

Comment: @LB-- I had a similar issue, and `git check-ignore -v` told me it was because of `~/.gitignore`

Comment: @gurneyalex I found out that it fixes itself if I delete the local repo and re-clone it, it must be a bug.

Comment: Is the /*/ necessary?

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to add `!/bin/` to my root `.gitignore` file, but then additionally I had to add a `/bin/.gitignore` file with `!*`... Making only one of those changes didn't work. It only worked after combining both changes.

Comment: @LB and others, try `/stuff/*` and `!/stuff/specific/`. The difference is `/stuff/` tells it to ignore the stuff directory itself, `/stuff/*`says ignore all directories in the stuff directory, then don't ignore this specific directory. That made the difference for me.

Comment: To make sure it works, after updating your .gitignore as the above, run `git init`, `git add .`.

Comment: @reads0520's comment worked for me.

Comment: This is, hands down, THE correct answer.

Comment: @reads0520 I would upvote 1000x if possible.  This needs to be its own Q&A.  It is too common of a problem.

Answer (score 143):

Here how to ignore everything exept one directory "**MY_SUPER_DUPER_TEMPLATE_directory**" in some directory

Structure: /bitrix/templates/**MY_SUPER_DUPER_TEMPLATE_directory**

```
/*
!/bitrix
/bitrix/*
!/bitrix/templates
/bitrix/templates/*
!/bitrix/templates/MY_SUPER_DUPER_TEMPLATE_directory
*.DS_Store
*.gitignore
```

Comment: This worked wonders for unignoring a laravel vendor package I had modified! Thank you, you saved me lots of headaches

Answer (score 79):

You must exclude everything on the way to the destinations, but you must include the destinations:

*Note: This is an exclusion file (i.e. .gitignore) so the logic is inverted. Ignore all, except the tsp directory, ignore all in tsp directory, except the src directory...*

```
/*
!/tsp
/tsp/*
!/tsp/src
/tsp/src/*
!/tsp/src/*.h
!/tsp/src/*.cpp
!/tsp/src/data.txt
!/.gitignore
```

Comment: +1 for the principle of including a directory, then, excluding it's contents, then, including the desired sub-directory, etc.  I ended up using this answer on my projects.

Comment: Fast forward a few years and it kind of feels off that you still have to be this verbose. Specifying the final destination should be enough.

Answer (score 47):

The only issue you have is that the `bin` directory itself is not matched by the `bin/*` pattern so git isn't even look in the `bin` directory.

There are two solutions that spring to mind.

`.gitignore` :

```
*
!/bin/
!bin/*
```

or

`.gitignore` :

```
*
!/bin/
```

`bin/.gitignore` :

```
!*
```

I prefer the second solution as the first solution won't stop ignoring files in the `bin` directories that are in subdirectories that aren't called `bin`. This may or may not matter in your situation.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have to have a .gitignore like this to make it work:


`# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files...
!/wp-content/
!/wp-content/plugins/
!/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/
!/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/*`

No block code in comments?

Comment: [Tyler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8594971/165673) has better single file solution

Answer (score 27):

From the official [git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), one of the examples says:

Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo/bar):

```
$ cat .gitignore
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
```

For an explanation about the leading slash: [When to use leading slash in gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139478/when-to-use-leading-slash-in-gitignore).

Comment: Thank you a million, this worked for me! Note to others that the order of the lines here is important, you can't have !/foo/bar before /foo/* for example.

Answer (score 17):

Try following in latest GIT version.

```
*
!*/
!/path/to/your/dir/**
```

Comment: it should actually be !/path/to/your/dir/** for the last line

Comment: @faham, yep, just added it.

Answer (score 12):

I think a better way would be to anchor each pattern to the top git directory by starting the pattern with a slash:

```
/*
!/public_html
!/.gitignore
```

Instead of ignoring all files it will only ignore top level files, not the ones in the directory you dont want to ignore.

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party, but none of the answers worked for me "out of the box". This one does:

```
* 
!bin
!bin/**
```

- the first line ignores everything
- the second line includes back "bin" directory itself
- the last line includes back entire content of the "bin" directory no matter how nested it is (note double asterisk),

Answer (score 9):

This `.gitignore` works for me:

```
*/
/*
!bin/
```

Answer (score 6):

try this obscure git bug.

```
!bin**/**
```

Hope it helps :)

Supporting docs [git bug sample](https://github.com/DavidMont/test111)

PS: try it first before commenting.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this recently:

```
*
!sub-dir/
!sub-dir/*
```

I'm not sure why I need two lines for to exclude one folder, but this is what worked for me and macos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. In my scenario I had a folder with subfolders as follow:

- database (main folder)

  - conf (subfolder)
  - drivers (subfolder)
  - jars (subfolder)
  - sql (subfolder)

And from the **database** folder I wanted to push the **sql** folder only so my `.gitignore` file was as follow:

```
database/*
!database/sql/
```

Where the first line simply say ignore all subfolder(s) of the **database** folder and the second line meaning since you are ignoring all subfolder(s) of the **database** folder exclude(don't ignore) the **sql** subfolder

Answer (score 0):

To me it turns out I should not ignore the parent folder but files and folders in it using `/*`

```
-- **/node_modules

++ **/node_modules/*
```

then

```
++ !node_modules/@my-package/
```