# opposite of .gitignore file?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Is it possible to let git ignore all files by default, unless specified in a special file?

Comment: As sehe says, the "ignore everything then specify exceptions" approach is probably easiest - see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/987142/223092 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1248570/223092

Comment: Not really a duplicate. Solution may be a duplicate, but the idea is to only track listed files. IE. config files in user's home directory on Linux.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can include !-lines to whitelist files: a .gitignore with:

```
*
!included/
```

will exclude all, but the 'included/' directory

Note that if you want files matching a pattern to be un-ignored, in subdirectories, you will need to prevent the containing directories from getting ignored too. This should not pose a large problem, since git doesn't actually track directories, only files (identified by a repository path).

Example:

```
*
!*/
!SOURCES
```

will ignore everything, except `SOURCES` in subdirectories.

Comment: And of course, this is all documented in [`man gitignore`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

Comment: link broken. Use http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore

Comment: it do not work for me when the path is a directory... just for files.

Comment: As shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/321973) you also need to add a `!*/` exception so parent paths are allowed (also @semente)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler That's a great addition. I have added it to the answer for posterity

Comment: Of course, you will probably also want to whitelist the .gitignore file: `!*.gitignore`

Answer (score 16):

You can use .gitignore for that.

```
*
!file0.txt
!file1.txt
```

In a case where you interested in file0.txt and file1.txt.

Comment: This will however not work for nested paths, for which you'll have to use [the `!*/` trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/321973)