# drupal 7 and git - only upate the site files

Tags: git, drupal-7, gitignore

I am using git to update my d7 site. I only really want to add the `/sites` folder and the `.htaccess` I suppose and leave all the core drupal files. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might add some details and infos about what you've tried. If you're looking for deployment tools, you should search for deployment tools.

Comment: I have not tried or want any deployment - this is just to keep  the files I am adding to the repo to a minimum.

Comment: I don't see what your problem is...

Comment: the problem is having to add lots of files so suppose I am looking for a gitinclude rather than a git ignore

Comment: You can actually use wildcards in .gitignore files. Also whitelisting is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011521/opposite-of-gitignore-file

Answer (score 0):

first create directory in git.and clone into local directory.then put your sites folder and .htaccess file in it.then push to git.after when u add new module your entire module folder copy into directory for git. then push. these process done every time when add new module.