# Whitelist nested files and folders using .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I want to exclude entire `android/` & `ios/` folder

And I want to include the following files in it:

```
android/settings.gradle
android/app/build.gradle
android/build.gradle
android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativegoogleadmob/MainApplication.java

ios/Podfile
ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/AppDelegate.h
ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/AppDelegate.m
```

So my `.gitignore` is:

```
# Remove following directories

android/*
ios/*

# Add following files

!android/settings.gradle
!android/app/build.gradle
!android/build.gradle
!android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativegoogleadmob/MainApplication.java

!ios/Podfile
!ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/AppDelegate.h
!ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/AppDelegate.m
```

But it only includes top level files like:

```
android/settings.gradle
android/build.gradle
ios/Podfile
```

I also tried `android/**/*` & `ios/**/*` but it gives same results as `android/*` & `ios/*`.

How do I include the rest of the files? I tried other solutions too but hitting a roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this thing work thanks to [@axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568924/6141587).

Read it before reading the solution below as it explains much better than I can explain -

```
android/*

!android/build.gradle
!android/settings.gradle

!android/app/
android/app/*
!android/app/build.gradle
!android/app/src
android/app/src/*
!android/app/src/main
android/app/src/main/*
!android/app/src/main/java
android/app/src/main/java/*
!android/app/src/main/java/com
android/app/src/main/java/com/*
android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativegoogleadmob/*
!android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativegoogleadmob
!android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativegoogleadmob/MainApplication.java

ios/*

!ios/Podfile

!ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/
ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/*
!ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/AppDelegate.h
!ios/ReactNativeGoogleAdmob/AppDelegate.m
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `.gitignore` file should have only these entries as it will ignore the files recursively inside `android` and `ios` directory.

**.gitignore**

```
android
ios
```

Comment: That ignores everything inside `android/` & `ios/` directory. I want to blacklist everything inside `android/` & `ios/` directory & whitelist the above mentioned files.

Comment: That's not a right way to do it. Add files to ignore list which needs to be ignored and rest of the files can be checked into the repository.

Comment: There are tons of files in `ios/` & `android/` folder which I can't one-by-one manually add it. Also, there is no wrong way as there are already solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6011532/6141587 but just not working for me :)