# Is there a .gitnotice file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory where I want to keep track of only a few files out of many.
The `.gitignore` file would become unnecessarily long compared to a `.gitnotice`.
Is it possible to tell git to ignore everything except the designated files?

Comment: Duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011521/opposite-of-gitignore-file), but I like the way you asked the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `!` character to negate patterns in `.gitignore`. So, for example, you could ignore an entire directory other than a couple of specific files:

```
dir_to_ignore/*
!dir_to_ignore/file_you_want_to_track
!dir_to_ignore/another_file_you_want_to_track
```