# Git will not pickup .tga files

Tags: git, binary, gitignore

I've got a directory structure as shown below. The / is the base of the Git repo, not root. I just inited the repo, I haven't hooked it up to any remote repository yet.

```
/ (In here is just a .dm file I want)
/LodumViralDeath/ (In here are some .tga files I want to keep)
```

I added a .gitignore file to / that looks like this.

```
*
!LodumViralDeath.dm
!LodumViralDeath/
```

And there are several .tga files inside of /LodumViralDeath/ but Git does not pick any of them up whne I do git status, instead it shows this.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       LodumViralDeath.dm
#       LodumViralDeath/
```

Not sure how to get it to recognize the fact that the binary .tgas are there!

And just as a sanity check, here's the directory listing. / is equal to /c/dominions3/mods/

```
$ pwd
/c/dominions3/mods/LodumViralDeath

$ ls
boomer1.tga  boomer2.tga  cultivatedBrainMass1.tga  cultivatedBrainMass2.tga  lodumbanner.tga  slimeDippedNecromancer1.tga  slimeDippedNecromancer2.tga  smokestack1.tga  smokestack2.tga
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ! directive undo the * ignore?

Comment: And there are plenty of examples with this, as shown here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're just confused by the output of `git status`. When `git status` shows a directory like the following line:

```
#       LodumViralDeath/
```

it means that there are some number of (untracked in this case) files in that folder. It only shows the folder to keep the output shorter.

If you want `git status` to show every file, use

```
git status -u
```