# Ignore everything but certain files - Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have this `.gitignore` file and it successfully ignores everything but `.bashrc`, `Readme.md`, `.gitignore`.

The problem is that `.setup/setup_java.sh` is also ignored and I can't solve this issue.

```
*
!.bashrc
!Readme.md
!.gitignore
!.setup/setup_java.sh
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: ignore everything except subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory)

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path instead? I.e. `!/.setup/setup_java.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
*
!.bashrc
!Readme.md
!.gitignore
!.setup
!.setup/setup_java.sh
```