# Git ignore bug?

Tags: git, gitignore

but this is really weird i was just typing base on what I read here [Gitignore Docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

this my weirdest solution:

```
#ignore everything
*
#except
!.gitignore
!directory**/**
```

actually this really works!, everything subfolders to what i really want is being seen using `git status`

**NOTE: I have not seen this in the docs or I was blinded by confusion and didnt see it in the docs**

Is there anyone who can let me understand why this works? I really want to learn git.

**EDIT : same solution to this one by lanzz**:

```
#ignore everything
*
#except
!demo
!demo/**
```

**EDIT**
Thanks,
David

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1248570/946850

Comment: No , no Im asking why this works.

Comment: @lanzz Im taking about this one `!directory**/**` <-- why is it working other than this `!directory/**` yes i read that. but why does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an obscure `git` bug to me — `!directory**/**` is an invalid usage of consecutive asterisks as per the manual, but it doesn't state *how* such invalid rules are handled.

The correct rules should be:

```
*
!directory/
!directory/**
```

The reason is that `*` matches all files *regardless of the directory they're in* (because it does not contain a slash), so `!directory/` will only allow the directory itself, but not its contents — you need to add `!directory/**` to match them as well. Using just `!directory/**` without `!directory/` won't work, as `!directory/**` does not match the `directory` itself and it will remain ignored.

**Edited:** `!directory/` is preferrable to `!directory` (without a trailing slash), as `!directory` will also match files and directories named `directory` deeper in the directory tree; this will not affect your case, but might be a gotcha in more complex `.gitignore` rulesets.

Comment: but a working (weird that does work) bug?
nice i never thought adding `!directory` or `!directory/` would do the job.

Comment: Apparently yes, it also works in my tests. I'd still suggest you change your `.gitignore` to avoid this invalid rule, as using undocumented functionality carries the risk of that behavior disappearing without notice.