# upload selected files and folder(subfolders) to github

Tags: git, github

I want to upload all the vim related files to git hub. I could not find information on how to do it for my scenario

My home directory structure

```
  Downloads
  Desktop
  Documents
  .vimrc
  .vim
    autoload
      <files>
    bundle
      <subfolders>
    colors
      <files>
    snippets 
      <files>
  <lot of other files and folders>
```

My expected git hub structure

```
 vim-essentials
   .vimrc
   .vim
      autoload
        <files>
      bundle
        <subfolders>
      colors
        <files>
      snippets 
        <files>
```

Basically I want to upload .vimrc file and .vim folder and all its contents onto a new github folder called vim-essentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .gitignore file with the following syntax:

```
*
!.gitignore
!.vim
!.vim/*
!vim.rc
```

More about [.gitignore syntax for including only a few specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory)