# Ignore Everything Except a Series of Different Files in Different Directories

Tags: git, magento, gitignore

Following on from these questions:

- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)
- [git: ignore everything except subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory)

I'm struggling to implement this in my own environment.

I've followed the advice and adapted it to my own needs, however, when I run `git status` all I get as untracked is the .gitignore itself.

I'm creating a Magento Module, which, if you've every created one, you'll know has files in odd locations throughout the Magento installation.

Here's the .gitignore I created:

```
# Ignore All
/*
/*/

# EXCEPT
# =============

# This
!/.gitignore

# Module Config
!/app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml

# Module Code
!/app/code/local/Company/Module/

# Front End Design
!/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/company_module.xml
!/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/company_module/

# Back End Design
!/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/company_module.xml
!/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/company_module/

# JavaScript
!/js/company_module/

# Front End Skin
!/skin/frontend/base/default/css/company_module/
!/skin/frontend/base/default/images/company_module/
!/skin/frontend/base/default/js/company_module/

# Back End Skin
!/skin/adminhtml/default/default/css/company_module/
!/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/company_module/
!/skin/adminhtml/default/default/js/company_module/
```

I created the following file to test its validity `/app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml`but it's not appearing at all within the `git status` output.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've worked out how this should be structured.

I have to treat each folder as it's own entity whilst creating the file. For example, I'll look at the root and use `/*` to ignore all, then go through each folder within this directory and negate what I need to negate, including negations **only** for the folders I want to negate. Instead of tracing the full paths for the files, I'd treat it on a folder by folder basis. See the below example:

```
/*
!/app
app/*
!/app/etc
app/etc/*
!app/etc/modules
app/etc/modules/*
!/app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml
```

Line by line:

1. Ignore every file in root - `/*`
2. Except the app folder - `!/app`
3. Within the app folder, ignore all files - `app/*`
4. Except the etc folder - `!/app/etc`
5. Within the etc folder, ignore all files - `app/etc/*`
6. Except the modules folder - `!/app/etc/modules`
7. Within the modules folder, ignore all files - `app/etc/modules/*`
8. Except the module configuration file - `!/app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml`

It's a little long-winded but it sure beats adding 400+ lines for ignoring each irrelevant file/folder.

I've structured the file this way, and it's expanded from 36 lines to 91 so it's not too bad. Everything has now been committed and pushed to my repo with this `.gitignore` structure and I can confirm it's validity.