# How to exclude a specific folder from ignored list in .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I have some temp folders in my source tree. I am ignoring them all in .hgignore like below

```
temp/
```

It is ignoring all the temp folders e.g.

```
a/temp
b/temp
a/c/temp
b/d/temp
```

But I want a specific temp folder for example "a/c/temp" to include in the repository. So I excluded it in .hgignore like below.

```
!a/c/temp
/temp
```

But it is not working. "a/c/temp" folder is still being ignored. 
Any idea?

Comment: take a look at the following question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory); it is for git, but it could work for mercurial

Answer (score 3):

You need something like that (*Negative Lookahead*):

```
syntax: regexp
^(?!a/c).*/temp
```

and if you want to exlude more directories, for example **b/d/temp**

```
syntax: regexp
^(?!a/c|b/d).*/temp
```

I hope that helps.