# Gitignore over-ignoring - ignoring files I am designating not to be ignored

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I've been trying to make it so the splash screen icons for my app won't be ignored by git. It started with node_modules/ plugins/ and platforms/ being ignored. Then I tried to just ignore all the directories and files that weren't what I needed. Thats what's below.

```
node_modules/
plugins/
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/Plugins
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/main.m
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/Classes
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/TruckBlox-Info.plist
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/TruckBlox-Prefix.pch
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/config.xml
platforms/ios/TruckBlox/Resources/icons
platforms/ios/build
platforms/ios/cordova
platforms/ios/CordovaLib
platforms/ios/platform_www
platforms/ios/TruckBlox.xcodeproj
platforms/ios/www

!platforms/ios/TruckBlox/Resources/splash/
!platforms/ios/TruckBlox/Resources/splash/*
```

So now it should be not ignoring the splash folder with all the splash screen icons. This isn't the case though, when I do a git add, none of these files show up as changes, and when I commit, the only change is the .gitignore, and when I push, of course, the only change is the .gitignore.

What's going on here?

Update - noticed that I wasn't in the root directory, then went to the root directory and made all the changes to that .gitignore, and this didn't work.

I even tried git add --force on all the .png icons. This didn't do anything either. It didn't even notice.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to ignore the `platforms/` directory anyway?

Comment: There was some type of error earlier along in the development process. I'm not sure what it is, but this is whats in the readme... having to platform remove and add

Comment: You might find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at a few other questions, but they aren't helping. The solution I tried is the solution they offer, then another attempt at being more specific about which files are ignored, hoping that would fix it through ignoring everything but those files. But this still isn't working. It's bizarre