# git ignore everything except nested folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a large code base (say, a wordpress installation) and want to ignore everything except the few files I myself changed (say, a theme). I know I can ignore files except some single files with

```
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
```

But if the directory I want to keep is deeply nested, this does not work. I tried:

```
/foo/*
!/foo/bar/baz
```

but `baz` is ignored as well. There is a [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11018557/1168892) in a different question that works like

```
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
/foo/bar/*
!/foo/bar/baz
```

but this grows to a damn PITA if the directory I want to keep is nested deeper.

**Is there a simpler solution to keep `/foo/bar/baz` but ignore everything else?**

Answer (score -1):

```
**
!/foo/bar/baz/**
```

Ignoring everything, except baz and subfolders.

Comment: i thought of a simple solution like this, but it doesn't seem to work. [demo](http://dominikschreiber.com/gitignore-demo.png), was expecting `untracked files: foo/`