# .gitignore for Joomla component

Tags: git, joomla, gitignore, joomla-component

I'm developing a Joomla! component named **com_proposta**.

I'm using git for version control.
I want git to ignore all Joomla files **except** the files in `administrator/components/com_proposta` and `components/com_proposta`.

Comment: A similar question was already answered here: [git: ignore everything except subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a gitignore file on git that you can use (and contribute to).

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Joomla.gitignore

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!` operator to negate ignoring in `.gitignore`. In your case:

```
* 
!administrator/components/com_proposta
!components/com_proposta
```

Answer (score 0):

This works better. We need to provide details for each directory what to include and what to exclude.

```
administrator/cache/*
administrator/components/*
administrator/help/*
administrator/includes/*
administrator/language/*
administrator/logs/*
administrator/manifests/*
administrator/modules/*
administrator/templates/*
!administrator/components/com_compname

bin/*
cache/*
cli/*
components/*
images/*
includes/*
language/*
layouts/*
libraries/*
media/*
modules/*
plugins/*
templates/*
tmp/*

!components/com_compname

configuration.php
htaccess.txt
index.php
LICENSE.txt
README.txt
robots.txt
web.config.txt
```