# Gitignore - Ignore only images & ignore everything except .. in single command

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I write to .gitignore:

1. to ignore only images ( .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif )
2. to ignore everything except videos ( .mp4, .flv etc )

using a single command each time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 1 Ignore images

```
printf '*.jpg\n*.jpeg\n*.png\n*.gif\n' >> .gitignore
```

## 2 Ignore everything but videos:

See [How do I tell Git to ignore everything except a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/git-ignore-everything-except-subdirectory)

```
printf '*\n!*.mp4\n!*.flv\n' >> .gitignore
```

Comment: you mean something like this? for 1st: /my_folder/*.jpg\n*.jpeg\n*.png\n*.gif\n

Comment: for 2nd: /my_folder/*\n!*.mp4\n!*.flv\n

Comment: Yes, you may have to prefix the strings with a folder