# .gitignore - ignoring image files not working

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have this `.gitignore` file:

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist
screen

# local env files
.env.local
.env.*.local

# Log files
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
pnpm-debug.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
*.sw?

# Vue Browser Extension Output
*.pem
*.pub
*.zip
/artifacts
```

I'm trying to add a rule that will tell to git to ignore the `.jpeg` or `.jpg` and `.code-workspace` files, but the added rules added are ignored when I push the repository online and these files are anyway copied. Is this syntax correct?

```
# Ignoring psd and image files
*.jpg
*.psd
# Ignoring VS workspace files
*.code-workspace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in `.gitignore` looks good.

What about your repository: are the`.jpg` and `.jepg` files pushed to the repository? If the files stay already in the repository (`git push` already executed), you must untrack this file. Then after push the file Git will tracked this added files and any skipping matching rules will be skipped.

With following command you can removes the file from the repository without physically deleting:

`git rm --cache folder/to/the/imagefiles`

After committing that change, all files will be removed from the repository, and ignoring should work properly.

[git rm](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/) documentation.

Comment: no, the files are't pushed to the repository at the moment, I'm facing this problem with some repository that I need to push. So you suggest me to untrack that files?

Comment: if your repository isn't pushed, then you must just untracked your file, when you've already done `git add` or `git commit`. If you are not sure, untrack the files, nothing can happen, you don't deleting the files physical, only the files from the repository!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might need to include additional formats, have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071351/gitignore-ignore-only-images-ignore-everything-except-in-single-command) specifically at this `printf '*.jpg\n*.jpeg\n*.png\n*.gif\n' >> .gitignore` line.

In your case you can just add to your .gitignore

> *.jpg
> *.jpeg
> *.png
> *.gif
> *.tiff

Comment: So I need to add the file formats to ignore using cli nor by adding them manually into the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: you can add them manually so instead of the one liner you can just copy/paste them