# Git Ignore a dir except certian dir's

Tags: regex, git, gitignore

Ive been trying to understand git pattern format in order to not ignore  certain common directories inside node_modules

I have more than 20 directories all of them share the same three chars, I am trying to figure out a pattern to exclude these dir's from gitignore

example

```
 node_modules
 |
 |apifoo
 |apibar
 |apix
 |..
 |..
```

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do gitignore exclusion rules actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001888/how-do-gitignore-exclusion-rules-actually-work)

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568924/4265352) on a similar question.

Comment: You should ignore `node_modules` completely. Why would you track its content?

Comment: @axiac  wired project, where controllers are inside node_modules as npm packages, cant modify the packages since they are private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

so something like !node_modules/api*

Answer (score 0):

Avoid excluding node_modules as directory, instead exclude all it's files!
since excluding a directory as @markus said will not let git pay attention to any rule inside that directory.

excluding node_modules be like `node_modules/` which is not what you want, in your case you wanna tell git: please exclude all files inside node_modules dir not node_modules it self and this could be achieved by `node_modules/*` then add a negation to include any dir starts with api by `!/node_modules/apihawk*/`