# Why is the exception to gitignore not working?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have two lines in my `.gitignore` file:

```
somedir/local/*
!somedir/local/ssh/.gitkeep
```

However even the file `.gitkeep` in `somedir/local/ssh` seems to be ignored. which is evidently not what I wish. (I do wish all other files in `somedir/local/ssh` to be ignored).

If I don't use a nested directory but rather:

```
somedir/local/*
!somedir/local/.gitkeep
```

And put the file there it is working as expected.

I've also tried (ideal solution) to allow "gitkeep anywhere, never ignore any file named that way"

```
somedir/local/*
!.gitkeep
```

However this once again does not consider a file that is situated in a subdirectory that would be ignore (ie `somedir/local/gitkeep`) and only in the directly ignored directory.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568924/4265352) answer your question?

Comment: Maybe your question is a general one, but as written it's kind of weird to *not* ignore just a single file name. If you know what it is, then either it's added already in which case the `.gitignore` is pointless, or you think it's going to be added in the future, in which case you can probably just add it now, even if it's just a blank file.

Comment: Well the idea of not ignoring .gitkeep is the ability to setup folder structures even in local only files.

Answer (score 1):

This rules set should give the desired behavior:

```
somedir/local/**
!somedir/local/ssh
!somedir/local/settings
!.gitkeep
```

If you just want to maintain directory structure, instead I would recommend to have only one rule:

```
somedir/local/**
```

and commit every `.gitkeep` file forcefully:

```
find . -name '.gitkeep' | xargs git add -f
git commit
```

Comment: I wish to also ignore everything under `somedir/local/ssh` *except* the file `.gitignore` - but there are many such directly like `ssh`

Comment: You are contradicting yourself, in your original question you say you do not want `test` in `somedir/local/ssh` to be ignored.

Comment: yes but I do want `abc` in `somedir/local/ssh` to be ignored. I also notice I wrote "test"  in the text while I meant `.gitkeep`. Sorry if that confused people

Comment: is it possible to generalize this? IE I not only have `somedir/local/ssh` where I wish to keep `.gitkeep` but also `somedir/local/settings` and other directories.

Comment: Yes, to some extent, see the update. You will need at least to list the directories which may contain `.gitkeep`. I would instead recommend to forcefully add/commit `.gitkeep` files and only keep one single rule `somedir/local/**`.