# How can I ignore everything except two directories (nested)?

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is my root which git is installed there:

```
htdocs/
    .git
    xampp
    test
    myweb
    myweb_dependencies
    onOtherProject
    php_info.php
    .gitignore
```

Also here is the content of `.gitignore`:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files
!myweb
!myweb_dependencies
```

What I want to do is *ignoring everything except these two directories: `myweb` and `myweb_dependencies`*.

The problem is: apparently the content of `.gitignore` is wrong, because it doesn't track changes into `myweb` directory. How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell Git to ignore everything except a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-everything-except-a-subdirectory)

Comment: @Martin AJ can you try appending a `/` to your "But not these files"?

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
# Ignore everything
/*
/*/

# But not these files
!/myweb/
!/myweb_dependencies/
```