# Gitignore subfolder, except files with a specific name

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got a large repo in which I'm downloading a large number of vsix files (visual studio and azure devops extension), then extract these and run a number of tools over them.

I'd like to keep some of the files in the extracted folder in my git repo, but ignore most of the rest (it's 30GB).

My folder structure looks like this:

```
\vsixs
   \publisher
       \extension
           \1.2.3
               \results-code.json
               \extension.vsixmanifest
               \extension.vsomanifest
               \taskname
                   \task.json
                   \node_modules
                   \index.js
            \...
         \...
      \...
somescripts.ps1
.gitignore
```

- I'd like to track all files in the root of the repo in git.
- I'd like to ignore most of the files under `vsixs/`
- I want to track all files named `results-code.json`
- I want to track all files named `task.json` (can live at deeper levels)
- I want to track all files named `extension.*manifest` (can live at deeper levels)

I've tried a number of things in my `.gitignore`

```
vsixs/
!vsixs/**
!result-code.json
!extension.*manifest
!task.json
```

And a number of other permutations... and [read a number of other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/736079), but am yet to stumble on anything that works.

I think, due to performance optimizations that the format I should specify should be oddly specific, but I can't figure out how specific...

Comment: [also related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1248570/1256452)

Answer (score 2):

## Summary

The magic you want is:

```
!*/
```

Remember that it's somewhat expensive; use it wisely.  (Combine it with `!/*` to un-ignore everything in the root of your working tree.)

## Long

As always, the issue here is a mismatch between Git's *storage format* (as seen in commits), and your OS's storage format.  Git handles only *files*—never folders—but the file names include forward slashes, e.g., `somescripts.ps1` and `vsixs/publisher/extension/1.2.3/results-code.json`.  Your OS, meanwhile, insists that there's no such file name as `vsixs/publisher/extension/1.2.3/results-code.json`.  Instead, there's a *folder* named `vsixs`; inside that folder is a sub-folder named `publisher`; and so on.  Eventually we get to a *file* named `results-code.json` (or some other name).

**Git must bridge this gap for you:**

- Git does so during `git checkout` or `git switch` quite easily, by *creating* folders on demand: if Git needs to check out a file named `vsixs/publisher/extension/1.2.3/results-code.json`, it goes ahead and creates `vsixs`, then `vsixs\publisher`, and so on, as needed, until your OS is willing to create *file* named `results-code.json` in the appropriate folder.
- Git does so during `git commit` by having Git's *index* contain a file named `vsixs/publisher/extension/1.2.3/results-code.json`.  This files goes into Git's index (aka "staging area") at the time you check out the commit, which is the same time Git created all the folders (if they did not already exist).
- Git does so during `git add` with ... well, how?  **This is where the problem occurs.**  It's `git add` that *updates* the copies of files that exist in Git's index, which is fine for files that already exist there because they were copied out of some earlier commit.  But for *new* files, it's not so fine.

So: If a file named `vsixs/publisher/extension/1.2.3/results-code.json` is *already in Git's index*, `git add -u` or some other en-masse `git add` will generally find and update it, since Git already knows to look for it.  But if it's *not* in Git's index, Git has to *search for it*, and this searching is very slow on many systems.  This kind of searching literally requires that Git open every folder everywhere and read the folder's content:

- the folder named `vsixs` has, as its content, sub-folders and/or files;
- the sub-folder `publisher` inside `vsixs` has, as its content, more sub-folders and/or files;
- and so on.

For each folder, Git can laboriously open it (e.g., open `vsixs`), read all its entries, get both the short name (`extension`) and the constructed full name (`vsixs/publisher`—note the forward slash here), and if that's a file, `git add` if that's appropriate, and if that's a folder, open and read *it*, recursively, to find more files and folders, and so on.

To speed this process up, **if you give Git permission to "ignore" a folder during this scanning process, Git does so**.  So if Git is allowed to "ignore" `vsixs`, it *simply does not open and read it* and therefore never discovers `publisher`, much less anything *in* `publisher`.

## The solution is now clear(ish): tell Git not to ignore some or all folders

If Git *must* look inside some folder in your working tree, Git *cannot* ignore that folder.  Git can ignore some or all of the *files* in that folder, but it must open and read the folder itself.  So don't give Git permission to skip that folder.

If you know the precise name of any particular folder, you can list that as a "do not ignore" exception:

```
!/vsixs/
```

for instance, in the top level `.gitignore` in your working tree, says that Git must open and read `vsixs`.  (Should there be a `vsxis/vsixs/`, that's a different name, because `/vsixs` requires that the name end there, so this does not force Git to un-ignore that *sub*-`vsixs`.)  Or:

```
!vsixs/
```

works similarly, except that it "un-ignores" *any* folder named `vsixs`.  There's something odd going on here with the two slashes, which we'll get to in a moment.  For now, just remember that this only works on entries named `vsixs`.  If we want *all* folders, we need `*`, or rather, `*/`:

```
!*/
```

As always, the leading `!` means that this is a specific *do not** ignore* entry.

#### The slashes

What's the difference between `a`, `/a`, `a/`, `a/b`, `a/b/`, `/a/b`, and so on?  There are two obvious differences and one less-obvious one:

- some *start with* slash;
- some *end with* slash; and
- some *contain* a slash that's not at the front or the back.

For `.gitignore` rules, the *starts with* and *contains in the middle* both have the same effect: they both "anchor" this ignore rule.  The *ends with* has a different, separate meaning: it means *only match a folder*.

An *un-anchored* ignore rule—one that doesn't start with slash, nor (after removing any trailing slash that means "folder") contain a slash—has Git look *only at the short name component*.  That is, if Git is reading `vsixs` and comes across `publisher`, Git uses the short part, `publisher`, as the name for the un-anchored tests.  But it uses the longer, constructed, `vsixs/publisher` for the anchored tests.  (Again, Git always uses a *forward* slash at this point.)

We'll mostly gloss over the trick Git uses for *nested* `.gitignore` files, which is that these constructed names start at the same level as the `.gitignore` file that was the source of the rule.  For a top-level `.gitignore` file, this doesn't skip anything, so it's just the full path.

As noted in the parenthetical remark above, the *trailing* slash means *match if and only the actual thing found, by reading the OS's folder in the working tree, is itself a folder*.  So we'll make use of that to force Git to *read folders* without also forcing Git to *un-ignore files*.

#### The bottom line

If we *know* the name of a folder we want searched, we list it:

```
!vsixs/
```

for example.  This allows Git to ignore *other* folders.

If we *don't* know the name of the folder, we have to use a pattern.  If we know nothing at all about the name, we must use:

```
!*/
```

which tells Git: *if it's a folder, open and read it*.

Since these are un-anchored—they neither start with, nor contain in the middle, a slash—they apply to *all* folders here and at any deeper level.  That makes this last one expensive.  If you can be sure that they should only apply at *this* level, you can put the `.gitignore` file here and use:

```
!/*/
```

to reduce its cost.  Since `vsixs` is a known name, if you know its level, you can write:

```
!path/to/vsixs/
```

or:

```
!/vsixs/
```

and it's now an *anchored* rule and applies only to the one specific `vsixs`, which in theory makes it even cheaper (though if there's hardly anything named `vsixs`, it's pretty cheap to start with, so this might be negligible anyway).

Hence, to ignore *all files*, then *un-ignore specific files and all directories*, the rule would read:

```
*
!*/
!.gitignore
!file-to-keep
```

These un-ignore rules could go in any order since Git applies all rules to each entry it finds as it reads through folders.  The *last matching* rule wins.  So as Git scans through the top level, it finds:

- `.gitignore`.  This does match `*`, doesn't match `*/`, does match `.gitignore`, and doesn't match `file-to-keep`.  The matched entry is negated (has a leading `!`) so `.gitignore` is not "ignored": it's considered for `git add`-ing if untracked, and not complained-about as an tracked file.
- `vsixs`.  This does match `*` and then `*/`, but does not match either other rule.  The last matching rule says *do not ignore* so Git opens and reads it recursively.

Note that you can put a `.gitignore` file down as far as needed, provided Git opens and reads that folder.  The one folder Git *is* guaranteed to open-and-read is the top level of the working tree.  After that point, the ignore rules kick in.

Comment: My brain still explodes.

Comment: Think about the recursive process of `git add`; it will *eventually* make sense. Once you understand recursion, that is. Of course, to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. 

Comment: I understand recursion... That ain't the problem... But the fact that gitignore is mixing 2 things seems to break me. It the file would simply be used to ignore things and skip the perf bits, then the format would be much easier to grok. It `git check-ignore` would propose what to change, would help a lot too. Now I'm wondering how to ignore-ignore-ignore the node_modules files in those folders again to speed things up again...

Any chance you could reason through what the final ignorefile would look like?

Comment: I like to use as many `.gitignore` files as make sense, to make this easier: for instance, in any build folder (node_modules) I'd create a `.gitignore` that just says `*` and `!.gitignore`, meaning "don't keep anything except this one file". This also means that Git will create the folder for you on checkout.

Comment: Once you decide *not* to use this method (i.e., decide to cover everything with a top level `.gitignore` for instance), you run into the fact that every sub-directory produces an anchored rule, so that if you don't know how many sub-directories you might accumulate over time, you have to make heavy use of `**`, which messes with figuring out what is going on.